# Highstock control: decrease y space between series

Tags: highcharts

How can I decrease space between series on a Highstock control? See attached image: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using this example: http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/candlestick-and-volume - just set proper values for `height` and `top` for y-axes